# Getting the style of the word surrounding the current cursor position

Tags: javascript, cpu-word, selection, range, styling

I'm trying to get the style/bold,italic,etc/ of the word under the current cursor position. 
I have the `x` and `y` coord of the click and I've done the following

```
var range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(x, y);
range.expand('word');
range.queryCommandState('bold');
```

but this leads to error that range does not have `queryCommandState` method whilst this reading: http://help.dottoro.com/ljkxwclp.php implies that range or at least text range (I'm JS newbie so pardon me about that) has such a method. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: I kinda workaround this by adding

```
var range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(x,y);
range.expand('word');
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
document.queryCommandState('bold');
window.getSelection().empty();
```

but I'm not very happy with it. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: If you follow the example on that page, they use `document.queryCommandState("bold");`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes. But this will only work in case we have a selection whilst when the user just moves the cursor there isn't any selection.

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: the android natve browser - it's running webkit as layout rendering engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do any better than what you've got without writing lots of code. IE's proprietary `TextRange` has a `queryCommandState()` and related methods but that's never made it into Range in other browsers.

If you're unhappy that you need to destroy the selection to do the bold testing, then I agree that it seems unnecessarily complicated and clunky, but it is simple to restore the selection to its original state. Also, the standards-based way to empty the selection is `removeAllRanges()` rather than `empty()`, which is WebKit-specific.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GkWTb/1/

Code:

```
var range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(x, y);
var sel = window.getSelection();
var selRange;

// Save initial selection
if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
    selRange = sel.getRangeAt(0);
}
range.expand("word");
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
alert( document.queryCommandState("bold") );

// Restore original selection
sel.removeAllRanges();
if (selRange) {
    selRange = sel.addRange(selRange);
}
```